# Does REST send its payload in the URL of the request? What about SOAP?

Tags: http, rest, soap

Do SOAP and REST put their respective payloads as a URL? For example:

`http://localhost/action/?var=datadatadata`

I know SOAP uses XML and sometimes runs on a different port on the server, but do you still submit data like the example above or do you send it as one big XML encapsulated packet to that port?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your HTTP method. GET method will put everything into URL while POST method only put path information in URL and the rest of them are streamed into the HTTP request body.

SOAP should also rely on HTTP protocol and hence should follow the same rule. Check out http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part0/#L10309